# Automatically select most recent log entry in Xcode 4

Tags: logging, xcode4

In Xcode 4, I have detached a new window and configured it to only show the logs via the *Log navigator*. I want it to display the log for the current application launch.

Each time I relaunch my application, I have to click on this window to select the most recent log.
How can I tell Xcode to automatically do this for me?

The little clock button at the bottom of this window helps a bit by having only the most recent log entry displayed, but I still need to manually select it.
[image: Log navigator filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- Open a new window.
- Select the *Log Navigator* (Command-7)
- Hide the *Navigator* (Command-0)
- Show the *Debug Area* (Shift-Command-Y)
- Expand the *Debug Area* to use all frame of the window
- Bonus: hide the toolbar (Main Menu > View > Hide Toolbar).

You now have a window with the logs of the current application launch.
Put it on your external display, and enjoy :)

Here is how it looks:

[image: Xcode 4 Log Window]